# How to create an ios headless simulator through terminal

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, integration-testing, headless

I understand there is already a way to launch an ios simulator from a terminal, but I've not seen one where I can launch an ios headless simulator like android does it. For example:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26 -no-audio -no-window
```

Is it even possible at all?

Comment: Headless you mean without a window? It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, without a window.  I'm trying to setup for automated integration testing running an app built with the flutter framework.